# Cordova: WebRTC media refused

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, sip

I want to build a cordova application on android that can use WebRTC to call and receive calls. I have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
```

in my android manifest, but when I use SIPML5 to call, it tells me media stream permission denied. (See SIPML5 live demo at http://www.sipml5.org/call.htm if required). I tried on the Google Chrome browser on my computer and on my android and it works perfectly. It asks to use my microphone, and I allow. But, once I try it as an cordova application on my android, it doesn't ask me anything, it just refuses the media.

Comment: did you find anything more on this?

Comment: yes, I installed crosswalk plugin and used sip.js instead, works fine.